# HTTPS request unexpectedly changed to HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API service where I'm using HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme to verify that the request was made using https.

I also have a test client that uses RestSharp to construct the request, and the base URL for this request uses https.

When I host the service locally it recognizes when I make a request using https.  When I deploy the service to our hosting environment, it sees these requests as http.

What am I overlooking that would cause this conversion to happen unexpectedly like this?

Comment: SOLVED: The SSL certificate store somehow was corrupted and the SSL configuration needed to be recreated from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference for the future reader, IIS falls back to `http` if SSL cert is not properly set up or there is a problem accessing the cert store (access rights issue, corrupt cert, etc.).